# Import scss module in Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I want to import a SCSS file in my Nuxt project.

For this I tried to follow the documentation where I simply add the path with filename in css file as:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
css: ['@/scss/_introPage.scss]
```

But it gives error as

> Cannot find module '../scss/_introPage.scss'

My folder structure:

```
> components
> pages
> scss > _introPage.scss
> static
> store
> test
> nuxt.config.js
> package.json
```

How can I include the SCSS file and apply the global CSS into my project?

If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import css file from assets folder in nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278515/how-to-import-css-file-from-assets-folder-in-nuxt-js)

Comment: What if you try `css:['~/scss/_introPage.scss']`?

Comment: Btw, are you sure the error is not coming from elsewhere?

Comment: why do you use "SCSS" folder? as the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration) says, use "assets" folder. and then use "~/assets/css/main.scss" for example.

Comment: @hamid-davodi not sure that this is really making a difference. `assets` is indeed a nice convention but this should work even if it's located elsewhere, no reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your input.

I had to install sass, sass-loader@10 and fibers for it to work.

```bash
nom install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10 fibers
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt.js provides a good way to share global CSS files with a `css` option in nuxt.config.js

example:

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  
  // other options
  
  css: [
      // Load a Node.js module directly (here it's a Sass file)
     'bulma',
     // CSS file in the project
     '@/assets/css/main.css',
     // SCSS file in the project
     '@/assets/css/main.scss'
  ],
  
  // other options

}
```

in your case, you need to add sass and sass-loader to load sass, scss, less &... files in your projects.

```
SASS: yarn add sass-loader sass
LESS: yarn add less-loader less
Stylus: yarn add stylus-loader stylus
```

to share your global style files(scss, sass, & ... ) and other good features
you can use [Nuxt Style Resources](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources).

> Share variables, mixins, functions across all style files (no @import
> needed)

Add `@nuxtjs/style-resources` dependency using `yarn` or `npm` to your project with on of these commands:

`yarn add -D @nuxtjs/style-resources` or `npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/style-resources`

and then you can add `'@nuxtjs/style-resources'` in `buildModules` option in nuxt.config.js file import your global scss files like this:

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {

   // other options

   buildModules: [
   '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
   ],

   styleResources: {
      // your settings here
      scss: ['@/assets/scss/_introPage.scss'],
      sass: [],
      less: [],
      stylus: [],
      hoistUseStatements: true  // Hoists the "@use" imports. Applies only 
      to "sass", "scss" and "less". Default: false.
   }

   // other options

}
```

for more information see this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources